# Uploading a Photo to Server via JSON with Android

Tags: android, image, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a photo to my server. But I'm confused as to how to submit a multi-part request as JSON. Here's the code I have so far.

```
// Set up HTTP client.
HttpClient client = DefaultHttpClient();

// Multi-part content body.
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody content = new FileBody(source, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("user[photo]", content);

// Put method.
HttpPut method = new HttpPut(url);
method.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
method.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
method.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); 
method.setEntity(mpEntity);
response = client.execute(method);

// Result.
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

The error I get from my Rails server is:

```
Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents: [garbled data]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works with the Rails server.

```
// Target URL.
// Add '.json' to end of the URL. This will make Rails
// accept the request as JSON but yet allow the multi-part content
// encoding below.
String url = "http://blahblah.com/users/123.json"

// Set up HTTP client.
HttpClient client = DefaultHttpClient();

// Multi-part content body.
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody content = new FileBody(source, "image/jpeg");
mpEntity.addPart("user[photo]", content);

// Put method.
HttpPut method = new HttpPut(url);
method.setEntity(mpEntity);
response = client.execute(method);

// Result.
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Works!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this isn't android specific at all. This belongs in HTTP-related questions. I'll answer it though.

You can't send a multipart http message using `application/json` content type. You should use an appropriate multipart content type to your message. Though in your example you're only passing one part, so there's technically no need for multipart. However, this depends on what your Rails server expects as a request.

Comment: Vladimir. I figured out a way to actually make it work. You're right in that I can't set the headers for `application/json`. But I can set it on the URL level and Rails server will accept it. I'll post a proper answer below for this.